# Extract id with certain condition to a list or vector

Tags: r, row, extract, conditional-statements

Suppose I have a data frame `z`

```
id num
 1   5
 2   6
 3   7
```

and I want the list of `id` whose `num` is greater than `5`, in this case

```
c(6, 7)
```

I tried `x<-z[z$num>5,id]` but got a error message:

```
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: Close. You're looking for `z$id[z$num > 5]` or `z[z$num > 5,"id"]`

Answer (score 1):

You may try

`z <- data.frame(id=1:3,num=5:7)
x<-z[z$num>5,]
x$id`

This would give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd, when I run

```
z <- data.frame(
    id=1:3,
    num=5:7
}
x<-z[z$num>5,id]
```

I get the error "object 'id' not found." So maybe it's possible you have a variable named `id` somewhere else in your code.

But the idea is that `[,]` syntax required each part to be a numeric vector or a character vector. If you just type `id` it tries to find a variable named `id` that contains a list of columns you want. If you want to actually just get the "id" column without having to create a variable, you just need to specify the column name with a character literal. So

```
x<-z[z$num>5,"id"]
```

should work just fine.